# Grow container width (not height) , when inside text wrapping

Tags: html, css

I need some hint on how to control an effect of text wrapping on its parent div's width. I'm sure it's something easy , that I just don't see. I'm doing internet search for a couple of days already, but still nothing helpful found.

Ok, so let's say I've got the following simple code:

HTML

```
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu erat vitae justo finibus consequat. Sed quis mauris sed massa congue consequat. Phasellus vitae mattis odio, nec accumsan dolor. Phasellus est massa, semper ac elementum quis, accumsan a nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis quis mauris ac libero sagittis venenatis ut id diam. Suspendisse vulputate diam mi, eget iaculis diam venenatis in. Aenean erat augue, maximus et tellus a, convallis ornare justo. Sed ultricies sollicitudin urna ac blandit.

         </p>

    </div>


</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, 
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
}

.text-wrapper {

    width:50%;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;

}
```

When I resize my browser width, text inside .text-wrapper p is starting to wrap , increasing  .text-wrapper height.

While my task is to have a fixed height (no more than some value, let's say managed by max-height) and instead make .text-wrapper grow in width.

Please, let me know if there are any good CSS solution for that ? Or else I need to dive into JS.

Fiddle for your reference  - https://jsfiddle.net/Lhrwcze9/

Thanx guys

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhrwcze9/1/) using `calc()`

**CSS**

```
.text-wrapper {
    max-width: calc(960px - 50%);
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: I guess, OP wants to keep the height fixed and increase the width of `text-wrapper`..!

Comment: Hi, thanx for quick turnaround. Sorry I didn't mention that - I need the text to be fully visible, so  no scrolling, just adjust parent container (text-wrapper) width to fit the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jquery code to make a box resize :

```
var oWidth=$(window).width();
var textWrapperWidth=$(".text-wrapper").width();
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width()<oWidth)
    {
        diff=oWidth-$(window).width();
        if(diff>$(window).width()) //if width of window is too small increase height in that case
            $(".text-wrapper").css({"width":"50%","height":200+diff+"px"});
        else
            $(".text-wrapper").css({"width":"90%","height":"200px"});
    }
    else
        $(".text-wrapper").css({"width":"50%","height":"200px"});
});
```